# How does Session work in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, azure

How does Windows Azure handle `Session` is it InProc session or something else?

Also why should one not use `Session` and instead go for `Windows Azure Cache` to store transient data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session management in Windows Azure depends on how the application is deployed. If your application is deployed in `Windows Azure Website`, then InProc session will work. However if your application is deployed as `Windows Azure Cloud Service`, then InProc session will not work. Reason being the load balancer in front of your cloud service. In case of a cloud service, load balance works in a `Round Robin` manner and thus InProc session management would not work.

If you want, you can still use session in your cloud services however you would need to use a different session provider than default InProc provider. There is a session provider built on top of Windows Azure Cache which can be used (and is actually recommended). You don't have to make any changes in the code as far as session handling is concerned. Only thing that will change is an entry in your web.config file. Please see this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx.

Comment: any resource for Windows Azure internals?

Comment: we want to move our windows azure webrole and worker role to on premise server, within next 3 - 4 months, so what would we need?

Comment: For Windows Azure Internals, I recommend doing a search for `Mark Russinovich Windows Azure Internals` and you will find some really great presentations. `we want to move our windows azure webrole and worker role to on premise server, within next 3 - 4 months` - Not sure I understand this. I mean how it is related to your original question.

Comment: its related to my first comment, "Any resource for windows azure internals"

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your stuff is running in cloud today and you would want to move back in your data center. Do you intend to keep the application running as web/worker roles when they are ported back in your DC?

Comment: the web role would be on IIS as usual, and the worker role will be shifted to a glorified MSMQ over a Windows Service.

Comment: So we want to avoid any affiliations with Azure in coming months. So we are trying hard to avoid all Azure patterns.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid that won't be easy to answer :). At a very high level, you would have to abstract out everything so that when you move stuff around, all you would do are config changes. May I suggest you ask a separate question and there you list down all components (session management for one) that you're planning on using. I'm sure you will get some really good answers. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the info man, your other answers for Azure have helped me, which made me ask you so many questions as comments.